# Linux shell scripting for different tabs

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, command

I want a script,which after executing will open multiple tabs and a specified command will run on every tab.Basically that command is ssh i.e. for connecting to other machines.

Comment: You could make a loop using `screen` + `ssh` for each connection

Comment: what tabs do you mean? e.g. see `man gnome-terminal`

Comment: [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) is a nice alternative to [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this;

```
gnome-terminal --tab  --title "server1" -x bash -c "ssh -t user1@host1 'nohup yourCommand'" --tab  --title "server2" -x bash -c "ssh -t user2@host2 'nohup yourCommand'"
```